# Dropdown (Bootstrap 4 popper.js) links not working in when the site is converted to wordpress but works fine in the HTML version of the website

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I get this weird issue with my website's dropdown link.  https://dev.netrocon.com/tedtucson/  this is my html version of my clients website which works fine.

When i converted this site into wordpress everthing looks good but the navbar's dorpdown links are not working, when i opened the console to look what's happening during the click i see this issue.

wordpress website link http://dev.netrocon.com/tedtucson-wp

[image]

I'm not sure what's going wrong here...

Comment: Check the order of js files. jQuery needs to be at the very top.

Comment: Hi @anjanasilva the Default JQuery library is at the very top please check view-source:http://dev.netrocon.com/tedtucson-wp/

Comment: I'm not seeing any error in the wordpress link.

Comment: https://dev.netrocon.com/tedtucson-wp/ 
Hi @cjmling please choose any link from the work with us link on the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution. It's because dropdown toggle class got added to all the submenu's anchorlink. when i removed them the links work like cake! :)